# Measure RPM using LM2917N and ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I want to measure RPM of a metal wheel using an inductive proximity sensor (npn) and a LM2917N which is supose to convert frequency into voltage which I intend to read using an ESP32 since has 12bits ADC.

The wheel has 2 holes which will be "see" by the sensor and a diameter of 50mm. Basically for a complete RPM sensor needs to "see" 2 wholes. Considering the max speed of the wheel which I intend to measure is 5 km/h I made following calculations:

Max rpm of the wheel will be around 530 rpm.
For that rpm sensor will get max 1060 pulses per minute which means about 17.67 Hz

Min rpm which I would like to measure is 100 rpm which means about 3.2 Hz.

Now the concerns:
I see in LM2917N datasheet that the input voltage can be 0 and 28 V, in my setup will be powered at 12V and supply voltage I assume will be same 12V since proximity sensor is powered also on same power supply as LM2917N.

I am not able to do calculations of the C1, C2 and R1 based on my setup and also have to find a way to put the output voltage in range of 0-3.3V (esp32 limits)

Second help is needed to understand how to match the read voltage to frequency (eg - 1V means 10Hz or rpm...)

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

[image: Wheel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading datasheet : formula is Vo = R1 × C1 × VCC × f

with Vcc=12V, C1=0.1 mF and R1=100K  >>  V0=0.12V/Hz

for 18Hz, output will be 2.16V

so you can connect directly output to analog input and convert value as

```
int getRPM() {
    float V0 = 3.3 * analogRead(A0)/1024;
    float F = V0 / 0.12;
    int rpm = F * 60;
    return(rpm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try like this. But since esp32 has 12 bits adc shouldn t be /4096 instead of /1024 in the code part? Thanks a lot again !

Comment: you are perfectly right ! mea culpa

Comment: Me again :) I just got the LM now and looking in datasheed I have one more question if you allow me: in your answer, C1 and R1 you mentioned are the ones I did with blue in this picture? - https://ibb.co/JvScX67     (the ones wired to pin 2 and pin 4 ) Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello ! C1 to pin2 BUT R1 is on pin 3, not 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So capacitor from pin 3 (1uF) and resistor from pin 4(10k) remains like in schematic.

Comment: yes , like in datasheet schematic !